# How to find the timestamp of when Redshift privilege was granted?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift [GRANT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html) command to give access privilege at table/schema level to dbusers and dbgroups. Example code is

```
grant SELECT on all tables in schema xyz to group abc;
```

The question I need to answer is WHEN was a specific privilege was granted - basically when was the GRANT query being performed. Are there system log tables telling such information?

Answer (score 0):

I found one potential answer: I can query against [stl_utilitytext](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_UTILITYTEXT.html) table.

```
SELECT * FROM stl_utilitytext
WHERE lower(text) like 'grant%'
```

to know when the `grant` query was run, the downside is the table only include data for 7 days. Prefer longer retention period to show all the permission that granted since the table/schema was created.